# Unable to start XAMARIN's Android Device Manager emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have created android device as indicated in the microsoft documentation, but I get the error below when I want to test the device on Android device Manager :
[image]

i have Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7. 
are there any proposals at your place ??

And thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the version of your Visual Studio 2017 to 15.8 or later.

Please check the requirements. To use the Android Device Manager, you will need the following items:

- Visual Studio 2019 Community, Professional, or Enterprise.
- OR Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 or later is required. Visual
  Studio Community, Professional, and Enterprise editions are
  supported.
- Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin version 4.9 or later.
- The Android SDK must be installed (see Setting up the Android SDK for
  Xamarin.Android). Be sure to install the Android SDK at its default
  location if it is not already installed: C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Android\android-sdk.
- The following packages must be installed (via the Android SDK
  Manager):
     Android SDK Tools version 26.1.1 or late, Android SDK Platform-Tools 27.0.1 or later, Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 or later, Android Emulator 27.2.7 or later.

For mroe details, please check the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows

Comment: I followed all these instructions to install the sdk, and everything is correct. but I still receive the same error message. my version vs is 15.9.19

Comment: Do you use the Hardware acceleration for emulator performance? Try to accelerate with Hyper-V and then try again. If you get the same error, please unstall and reinstall the Android SDK.